# How to get list of file names and their sentence containing a specific search string?

Tags: xml, regex, bash, awk

I tried with following command on unix machine:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I {} cat  {}  | grep {"String to search"}
```

Though this works with text files but when i try it with xml files it is not able to display proper grepped text.Instead it displays whole xml file.

I think the possible reason behind this is absense of new line character in xml file that i use.

Example:
Search string: `"/1031/"`

Xml line containing search string: `<eventtype uri="{any_url}/1031/"/>`

To clarify a bit :

`ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I {} cat {} | grep -o "/1031"`

This gives output as:

/1031

/1031

/1031...

I also want the name of the file in which it belongs.

Comment: `grep` will print the whole line that matches.

Comment: So what you want to know is how to control `grep`'s output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep has a flag -o which only outputs the matching text.

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I {} cat {} | grep -o {"String to search"}
```

From your edit it looks like you need the "line" that contains the URL as well. By default grep will match greedily which means a regex to account for the XML formatting will still give you an incorrect result.

I can think of 2 possible options:

For the next examples, test.xml contains the string:

```
<eventtype uri="{www.example1.com}/1031/"/><eventtype uri="{www.example2.com}/1031/"/><eventtype uri="{www.example3.com}/1031/"/>
```

The first is to use the -P flag for grep to enable perl syntax and match lazily.

```
grep -Po '".*?/1031/"' test.xml
```

This outputs:

```
"{www.example1.com}/1031/"
"{www.example2.com}/1031/"
"{www.example3.com}/1031/"
```

The second is to use sed to manually append a newline after each match and pipe to grep:

```
sed 's/1031/1031\n/g' test.xml | grep 1031
```

Outputs:

```
<eventtype uri="{www.example1.com}/1031
/"/><eventtype uri="{www.example2.com}/1031
/"/><eventtype uri="{www.example3.com}/1031
```

I believe both methods should work ok on plain text files although you may need to conditionally use one of these methods on .xml extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Dear You could use below command

```
find -type f -exec grep -HPo '".*?/1031/"' {} \;
```

**Sample Output**

> [root@MUM03S001 ~]# find -type f -exec grep -HPo '".*?/1031/"' {} \;
>
> ./File:"{www.example1.com}/1031/"
>
> ./File:"{www.example2.com}/1031/"
>
> ./File:"{www.example3.com}/1031/"
>
> [root@MUM03S001 ~]#